# Hide flexbox element based on neighbor element size or value

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, flexbox

I am using a flexbox to have two adjacent elements floating on the same line together. The left element has some text and the right element has a number.

If the right element contains a value with at least 7 digits long ( > 999,999 or < -999,999) the left element with the text should be hidden to make room for the bigger value.

Any ideas of how to handle this problem? Should I make the logic based on the size of the right element or the value? I hope that I don't have to use something like a watcher.

Comment: Is it possible to add a check function when the contents of the right div are updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the <s>`"onchange"`</s> `"keyup"` listener:

```
document.getElementById("right").addEventListener("keyup", myCheck);
```

Works great:

[jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/xa60tzjw/1/)

It really depends if the right element is a textbox or not, if it's a textbox, keyup listener is the best, but if it's just a div, the onchange listener will work.

Comment: That works good for a textbox, but what happens if the right element (with the number) was just non-editable text and the value is just set and won't change?

Comment: Well if you know it's just going to be once you could call `myCheck` just once. Or, add the event listener at page load before it even gets a value. In the fiddle I commented if it's a div and not a textbox it'll work with the `onchange` event listener.